# How to merge a release branch back to master

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration

We have two major branches:

- `master` Updated by developers
- `release` Updated by CI. Developers don't push to this branch.

Our automated Continuous Integration works like this:

1. CI takes the latest version of the release branch
2. builds a systems
3. integrates the latest code from the master branch (without push)
4. runs all tests
5. if all tests are good: The version number gets updated and the release branch gets updated.

This has one problem:

The version number in the master does not get incremented.

If we would do this, there would be an endless loop, since CI thinks:

*ah, new changes on the master (it does not see that it is only the version number update). Let's test the code ....*

How to get the changes from CI back to the master?

We want to avoid a merge where all CI commits get into the master. On often updated repos there would be a CI commit daily. The result would be that there are too many CI commits in the git history. With "too many" I mean "too many" for the human eyes.

**Update**

We do "continuous integration". Twice a day the software gets tested. If it is stable the version number gets increased. There are no "release day" in our context.

We have development/feature branches. But I think this is not a part of the question. Merging into the master gets done by a developer. This is not automated.

Comment: Is the version number increase done via an actual commit to the codebase or in some metadata stored elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to continuously integrate changes coming from developers, in which case you should use the **same** branch (`master`), the CI system should simply lay a label on the master branch and use that (or pick the latest CI label laid by some other method) to do its work - all it does is verification of the integration branch at that label, it shouldn't normally do any commit on the codebase itself.

Using another branch just to implement CI is IMHO a convoluted way which will only bring you complications and trouble (like this very question, for example).

If indeed you want to use the `release` branch for a **release** you should **never** blindly pour in it changes from `master`. And you should **never** merge it back into `master` either since `master` now evolves into the **next release**. - the context of the 2 branches diverges, just because a change works in one branch doesn't mean it'll work in the other.

The `release` branch should have a gradually smaller rate of commits while nearing the release date (much smaller than the commit rate in `master`). If fixes for issues seen in both master and release are desired they should be cherry-picked and double-committed to the 2 branches with the verifications appropriate for each branch.

Comment: Yes, maybe there should not be a release branch. I update the question: We do "continuous integration". Twice a day the software gets tested. If it is stable the version number gets increased. There are no "release days" in our context.

Comment: But the current version number needs to be in the source. There must be some merging from the time to time :-<

Comment: Why does the current version number needs to be in the source?

Comment: Why the version number needs to in the source? For introspection at run time. For example `foo-tool --version` should display it.

Comment: That can be achieved by carrying the versioning info in the SCM system (as labels/tags) and stamping it at build time. If you absolutely must have it in the source code then you can't/shouldn't merge it back into `master` unless there were no other commits since the last one picked by the CI system that produced the respective version# otherwise it would not properly reflect the source code content/context.

Answer (score -1):

Well... how about switching strategies?

Work in development/feature branches, merge into master, ci releases master (or tags if you like).

For git the master is the official history of the project, branches exist only to contribute to the master.

I currently know of two (ok three with linux) different mainstream procedures working with git. 
One is the [github model](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/), the other one is [Gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow) model. Gitflow is a little bit more complicated, and also often not necessary.

Why invent a custom strategy when there are already two existing working solutions?

Comment: I updated the question: We have development/feature branches. But I think this is not a part of the question. Merging into the master gets done by a developer. This is not automated.

Comment: How to merge develop/feature branches into the master is not part if this question. Sorry.

Comment: I tried to explain to you, that what you want to do does not make much sense..."How to get the changes from CI back to the master?" was one of your questions. And I don't think the CI should do any changes to the software whatsoever.

Comment: If CI should not change to source and the source contains the version number. What update process for the version number do you suggest?

Comment: I would change the version number each time a feature gets merged in the master. So that master only contains valid releases. Additionally tagging the release with the according versions helps greatly.

Comment: I agree with @sharpner, this should be accepted answer. I think you'd benefit from creating a develop branch, using feature/bugfix branches for development, merging them back to develop, creating release branches from develop when ready, merging releases to master when complete, then starting the cycle again. Also, I will add that you would benefit from getting that version number out of your source code, and using git tags (via `git-describe`) to do your versioning for you.